# Rational Rhapsody API to create projects from a specific model

Tags: java, api, model, rhapsody

I'm trying to make a transformation from one specific model to a Rhapsody project. This means using Rational Rhapsody's API in order to relate my model's objects with Rhapsody's ones.

I've a very specific question: I want to relate an object that is higher than IRPPackage, but lower than IRPProject. I mean: a class that could be inside the project and that could contain different packages. Another way to say: an API interface located between project and package.

Any hint will be great for me!
Legarda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing between a project and a package.
However, you can create your "new Item" stereotype based on Package and set it to be owned by Project. This way you ave something that can contain Packages and is owned by the project; which means it is in the middle

[image]

[image]